# How do you calculate descriptive statistics before and after matching multiply imputed datasets?

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, matching, multiple-imputation, pooling

I'm trying to find the best way to calculate descriptive statistics following matching on a dataset with missing values (handled using multiple imputation). The purpose is to present this data as "Table 1" in a medical journal article. Using the `mice::selfreport` dataset as an example:

```r
library(mice)
library(miceadds)
library(MatchThem)

# Create new outcome variable from reported bmi (br)
selfreport$obese <- cut(selfreport$br,
                        breaks = c(0, 30, 60),
                        labels = c("Not obese", "Obese"),
                        right = FALSE)

# Impute
datasets <- mice(selfreport, m = 5)

# Match non-obese and obese participants based on age, sex and 
# education level (using coarsened exact matching)

models <- matchthem(obese ~ age + sex + edu,
                    data = datasets,
                    cutpoints = list(
                      age = c(30, 40, 50)),
                    k2k = FALSE,
                    method = "cem")
```

I appreciate that using `summary()` on a `mimids` class object gives me the means (though not standard deviations) of only one of the imputed (unmatched) datasets:

```r
summary(models)
```

```r
Summarizing            | dataset: #1

Call:
matchthem(formula = obese ~ age + sex + edu, datasets = datasets, 
    method = "cem", cutpoints = list(age = c(30, 40, 50)), 
                    k2k = FALSE)

Summary of Balance for All Data:
          Means Treated Means Control Std. Mean Diff. Var. Ratio eCDF Mean eCDF Max
age             46.3333       41.3021          0.4100      0.669    0.0915   0.1866
sexFemale        0.6343        0.5151          0.2474          .    0.1192   0.1192
sexMale          0.3657        0.4849         -0.2474          .    0.1192   0.1192
eduLow           0.4045        0.3438          0.1237          .    0.0607   0.0607
eduMiddle        0.4013        0.3529          0.0986          .    0.0484   0.0484
eduHigh          0.1942        0.3033         -0.2758          .    0.1091   0.1091

Summary of Balance for Matched Data:
          Means Treated Means Control Std. Mean Diff. Var. Ratio eCDF Mean eCDF Max Std. Pair Dist.
age             46.3333       47.1995         -0.0706     0.8012    0.0241   0.0897          0.4716
sexFemale        0.6343        0.6343          0.0000          .    0.0000   0.0000          0.0000
sexMale          0.3657        0.3657         -0.0000          .    0.0000   0.0000          0.0000
eduLow           0.4045        0.4045          0.0000          .    0.0000   0.0000          0.0000
eduMiddle        0.4013        0.4013          0.0000          .    0.0000   0.0000          0.0000
eduHigh          0.1942        0.1942          0.0000          .    0.0000   0.0000          0.0000

Sample Sizes:
              Control Treated
All           1751.       309
Matched (ESS) 1324.81     309
Matched       1751.       309
Unmatched        0.         0
Discarded        0.         0
```

And I understand that [pooling means and standard deviations](https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/data-analysis-after-multiple-imputation.html#pooling-means-and-standard-deviations-in-r) after multiple imputation is possible. So for example, to pool the mean and SD of age of unmatched obese and non-obese participants:

```r
datasets_long <- complete(datasets, action = "long", include = FALSE)
local({
  pool_mean <- with(subset(datasets_long, obese == "Not obese"),
                    by(subset(datasets_long, obese == "Not obese"), 
                       .imp,
                       function(x) c(mean(x$age), sd(x$age))))
  print("Non obese mean, SD")
  print(Reduce("+",pool_mean)/length(pool_mean), digits = 3)
  pool_mean <- with(subset(datasets_long, obese == "Obese"),
                    by(subset(datasets_long, obese == "Obese"), 
                       .imp, 
                       function(x) c(mean(x$age), sd(x$age))))
  print("Obese mean, SD")
  print(Reduce("+",pool_mean)/length(pool_mean), digits = 3)
})
```

```r
[1] "Non obese mean, SD"
[1] 41.3 15.0
[1] "Obese mean, SD"
[1] 46.3 12.3
```

Any insight or suggestions on the following questions would be extremely appreciated:

- Is it possible to also pool the frequencies of the categorical predictor variables (sex and education level, as well as others not used in the matching model) in the unmatched cohort?
- Is it possible to calculate similar descriptive statistics for the pooled matched cohort?

###### Update

My partial solution to calculating descriptive statistics for the pooled matched cohort. Only managed to get it to work for 1:1 matching. Frequencies and descriptive statistics in the matched cohort are pooled averages across imputations

```
models <- matchthem(obese ~ age + sex + edu,
                    data = datasets,
                    cutpoints = list(
                      age = c(30, 40, 50)),
                    k2k = TRUE,
                    method = "cem")
```

Extract all imputed datasets, excluding unmatched observations

```
models_long <- complete(models, action = "long", all = FALSE)
```

Sample size of matched cohort

```
models_long %>%
  group_by(.imp) %>%
  summarise(Freq = n() / 2) %>%
  pull() %>%
  summary()
```

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    309     309     309     309     309     309
```

Baseline characteristics of continuous variables of matched cohort

```
local({
  variable <- "x$variable"
  pool_mean <- with(subset(models_long, obese == "Not obese"),
                    by(subset(models_long, obese == "Not obese"), 
                       .imp,
                       function(x) c(mean(x$age), sd(x$age))))
  print("Not obese mean, SD")
  print(Reduce("+",pool_mean)/length(pool_mean), digits = 3)
  pool_mean <- with(subset(models_long, obese == "Obese"),
                    by(subset(models_long, obese == "Obese"), 
                       .imp, 
                       function(x) c(mean(x$age), sd(x$age))))
  print("Obese mean, SD")
  print(Reduce("+",pool_mean)/length(pool_mean), digits = 3)
})
```

```
[1] "Not obese mean, SD"
[1] 46.3 12.2
[1] "Obese mean, SD"
[1] 46.3 12.3
```

Baseline characteristics of [categorical variables](https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/data-analysis-after-multiple-imputation.html#pooling-chi-square-tests) of matched cohort

```
models_long %>%
  group_by(obese, etn) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), 
            Freq = n()/5,
            Percent = n()/(3090/2) * 100) %>%
  mutate(across(c(Freq, Percent), ~ num(.x, digits = 1)))
```

```
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'obese'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 4 × 5
# Groups:   obese [2]
  obese     etn            n      Freq   Percent
  <fct>     <fct>      <int> <num:.1!> <num:.1!>
1 Not obese Autochtone  1211     242.2      78.4
2 Not obese Allochtone   334      66.8      21.6
3 Obese     Autochtone   891     178.2      57.7
4 Obese     Allochtone   654     130.8      42.3
```

Chi-square test (if required)

```
local({
  # Conduct a chi-square test in each imputed dataset, and save as vector
  dk <-  models_long %>%
    group_by(.imp) %>%
    summarise(Xsquared = chisq.test(etn, obese)$statistic) %>%
    pull(Xsquared)
  
  ## Obtain degree of freedom
  df <- models_long %>%
    dplyr::filter(.imp == 1) %>%
    summarise(df = chisq.test(etn, obese)$parameter) %>%
    pull(df)
  
  # Pool the chi-square tests
  miceadds::micombine.chisquare(dk, df, display = TRUE, version = 1)
})
```

```
Combination of Chi Square Statistics for Multiply Imputed Data
Using 5 Imputed Data Sets
F(1, 6.31)=5.316     p=0.05851
```